# How to unit test Spring IntegrationFlow?

Tags: junit, spring-integration, dsl, spring-annotations

I have been using Spring Integration DSL to implement some messaging processing flow.

How can I actually unit test a single IntegrationFlow, can anyone provide me with an example on how to unit test i.e. transform part of this bean:

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow transformMessage(){      
    return message -> message               
            .transform(new GenericTransformer<Message<String>, Message<String>>() {
                @Override
                public Message<String> transform(Message<String> message) {

                    MutableMessageHeaders headers = 
                          new MutableMessageHeaders(message.getHeaders());
                    headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
                    headers.put("Accept", "application/json");                      

                    String payload = "Long message";
                    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
                    map.put("payload", payload);

                    String jsonString = null;
                    try {
                        jsonInString = mapper.writeValueAsString(map);
                    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
                        logger.error("Error:" + e.getMessage());                            
                    }

                    Message<String> request = new GenericMessage<String>(jsonString
                    , headers);                                     
                    return request;                 
                }
            })
            .handle(makeHttpRequestToValidateAcdrMessage())                                                     
            .enrichHeaders(h -> h.header("someHeader", "blah", true))
            .channel("entrypoint");
}
```

How can I test it?

Regards!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The same techniques described in the [testing-samples project in the samples repo](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples) can be used here.

The send a message to channel `transform.input` and subscribe to `entrypoint` to get the result (or change it to a `QueueChannel` in your test case.

Answer (score 4):

Seems for me "unit testing" means check the behavior of the particular part of the system, some small component.

So, in your case it is about that `new GenericTransformer`.

so, just make it as a top-level component and perform tests against its isolated instances!

The integration tests can be performed against the target `IntegrationFlow` as well.

Each EIP-component in the flow definition is surrounded with 
`MessageChannel`s - `input` and `output`. Even if you don't declare `.channel()` there, the Framework build implicit `DirrectChannel` to wire endpoints to the flow.

Those implicit get the bean name like:

```
channelBeanName = flowNamePrefix + "channel" +
                                BeanFactoryUtils.GENERATED_BEAN_NAME_SEPARATOR + channelNameIndex++;
```

So, since your `IntegrationFlow` is from Lambda, the input channel form the `.transform()` is just input of the flow - `transformMessage.input`.

The channel between `.transform()` and the next `.handle()` has bean name like: `transformMessage.channel#0`, because it will be a first implicit channel declaration.

The idea that you can `@Autowired` both of this channels to your test-case and add `ChannelInterceptor` to them before testing.

The `ChannelInterceptor` may play verificator role to be sure that you send to the transformer and receive from the a proper data as it is expected.

More info can be found here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-java-dsl/issues/23

Answer (score 1):

Example of DSL IntegrationFlows testing is on [github](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-java-dsl/blob/master/src/test/java/org/springframework/integration/dsl/test/flows/IntegrationFlowTests.java).